# Генерация случайных чисел на Java Android. Генерируются числа вне диапазона

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа

```
public static int rnd(int min, int max){
   Random rnd = new Random();
   return min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
}

public static int rnd(int max){
   return rnd(0,max);
}
```

далее в коде у мене генерируются случайное число

```
_l2 = rnd(7);
```

Большая проблема: на декстопе код работает, числа генерируются нормально, а когда запускаю тот же код на андроиде - в ряде случаев получал, что `_l2` равнялось 9.

Помогите.

Comment: Приведённый вами пример использует метод с один аргументом, но вы привели код метода с 2-мя аргументами. Может вы просто где-то опечатались?

Comment: Забыл указать код второй процедуры. Изменил пост, добавил код. Прощу помощи.

Comment: Возможно это у вас `InstantRun` сбоит. Т.е. после изменения параметра метода код на девайсе не меняется и использует старое значение. Попробуйте отключить `InstantRun` в настройках студии

Comment: мнээээ использую эклипс......

Comment: Подозреваю что Вы статик полями оперируете при вычислениях? На Андроиде это нужно делать очень внимательно.